# Firebase Storage TypeError: file.getBlob is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

In my app I would like to download files (.pdf and .xls) from Firebase storage.

I can generate a download link using `ref.getDownloadURL()`, but that link causes the browser to open a new tab before downloading or opening the target file.

In order to avoid this behavior, I can download the the file in javascript using `res = await fetch([the download URL])` and then `await res.blob()`

THIS WORKS FINE:

```
 const res = await fetch([downloadURL]);
 const blob = await res.blob();     
 const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 const anchor = document.createElement("a");
 anchor.href = url;
 anchor.download = [file_name];  // e.g. my_file.xls
 anchor.click();
```

However, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk) suggests that I can download the blob **directly** via the SDK using `getBlob()`

I have tried to download a list of the files in my storage bucket and to loop over these to get the blob as follows:

```
const storageRef = storage.ref().child("my_files");      
const list = await storageRef.listAll();   
const blob_array = await Promise.all(
  list.items       
    .map(async (file) => {
      const blob= await file.getBlob();
      return {
        name: file.name,
        blob: blob,
       };
     })
   );
```

however, I get an error:

> TypeError: file.getBlob is not a function

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#getblob) for `getBlob()` states:

> To use this functionality, you have to whitelist your app's origin in
> your Cloud Storage bucket. See also
> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

In order to test this, I have followed the referenced documentation and, using gsutil, I have set the CORS policy for my storage bucket as follows:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

I thought that this would have the effect of 'whitelisting' my apps origin (per the `getBlob()` documentation), but instead I still get an error as follows:

> TypeError: file.getBlob is not a function

How can I enable this `getBlob()` functionality?

Comment: That error looks like a problem with your code (which you're not showing here) rather than your configuration.  We can't see what `file` is.

Comment: Your primary problem is the Cloud Storage object's **Content-Type** and **Content-Disposition** are not specified correctly. Those headers provide hints to browsers on what to do when an object (URL) is clicked. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata

Comment: @DougStevenson - I am using a Vue application to loop over an array of 'files' to generate a table.  The files are loaded as follows:

 ```const storageRef = storage.ref().child("my_files");   
  const list = await storageRef.listAll();
  this.files = list.items;```  

Then for each file in files: `file.getBlob()`

`file.getDownloadURL()` does work here.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to show the relevant code instead of leaving it in a comment that's not formatted to be easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly that stated by the error - you're trying to call getBlob on an object that doesn't have that method.

Firstly, take a look at the documentation for [downloading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk).  It states that **since SDK version 9.5** there is a global getBlob function.  You're not using a new enough version of the SDK to get that function.  You're using the old version 8, and Reference objects don't have a getBlob method (scan the [API documentation v8 for Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.Reference) and you just won't see it).

If you want to use getBlob, you'll have to [upgrade to the v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and rewrite all your Firebase code to conform to the new APIs.  Then you will be able to use the new getBlob.

Comment: Thanks - the weird thing is that I am using v. 9.8.1 and the 'compat' configuration, per the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Compat is just a wrapper.  It doesn't add anything to 8.  New methods are not going to just appear in 8 by adding compat.  Maybe you can import the getBlob from 9 and call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to call a method on the StorageReference, when in fact you need to use the global getBlob function, with the StorageReference as the first argument in the function call.

Look at this example:

```
import { getBlob } from "@firebase/storage"
import type { StorageReference } from "firebase/storage"

export const downloadFile = (fromReference: StorageReference) => {
  getBlob(fromReference)
    .then((blob) => {
      console.log('blob: ', blob)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error downloading file: ', error)
    })
}
```